# Removing elements of 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 2D vector and I need to remove blocks that do not contain sufficient values:

```
typedef vector<double> iniMatrix;


bool hasInsufficientEnergy() {
return true;
}
vector<double> Audio::filter(vector<iniMatrix>&blocks, double sumThres, double ZeroThres)
{
  vector<double> totalEnergy;
  vector<double> totalZeroCross;
  double totalSum = sumThres * blocks.size();
  double totalZero = ZeroThres * blocks.size();

  vector<iniMatrix> blockked;

  for(unsigned i=0; (i < blocks.size()); i++)
  {
    totalEnergy.push_back(abs(this->energy(blocks[i])));
    totalZeroCross.push_back(zerocross(blocks[i]));

    if(!totalEnergy[i] > totalSum || totalZeroCross[i] < ZeroThres)
    {
        hasInsufficientEnergy();
    }else{
        //hasInsufficientEnergy();
    }
    iniMatrix::iterator erase_after = remove_if(blocks[i].begin(), blocks[i].end(),
                                                &hasInsufficientEnergy);
 }
 }
```

The problem is erase_after and comes up with an error message:

```
In function ‘_OutputIterator std::remove_copy_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, 
 _OutputIterator, _Predicate) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, 
std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, _OutputIterator = 
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, 
_Predicate = bool]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1302:   instantiated from ‘_ForwardIterator 
std::remove_if(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Predicate) [with _ForwardIterator = 
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, 
_Predicate = bool]’
Audio.cpp:105:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1227: error: ‘__pred’ cannot be used as a function
```

Anyone have any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you store energy and zero cross in vectors? You don't use the previous values. Did you mean to sum the total energy over all blocks so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`true` or `false` aren't function objects. If you want to use `remove_if` you must give it a pointer to function or function object, which takes a member of the collection as parameter and returns whether to remove it or not. Look at the example in [std::remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/)

AFAICS, you could replace the `remove_if/erase` into the `if` and simplify it to:

```
for(auto i=blocks.begin(); i != blocks.end(); )
{
    totalEnergy.push_back(abs(this->energy(*i)));
    totalZeroCross.push_back(zerocross(*i));

    if(!totalEnergy.rbegin() > totalSum || totalZeroCross.rbegin() < ZeroThres)
    {
        i = blocks.erase(i);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: but that just clears the values.. I need to actually remove the blocks so the 2D vector is smaller.. Could I re-size it?

Comment: @Phorce `resize()` doesn't guarantee deallocation. You must `swap()` with an empty vector instead.

Comment: `hasInsufficientEnergy` is a function, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: Oh, FFS, he changed the question. Grrrr.

Comment: @Phorce Just to be sure, do you want to remove `blocks[i]` from `blocks` or do you want to remove the contents of `blocks[i]` and keep `blocks[i]` as a member of `blocks`?

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche I want to remove blocks[i] from blocks so the size of blocks will only contain 47 elements and 59 will be deleted

Comment: @Phorce Ok, look at the modified answer. No `else` or `remove_if` necessary anymore.

Comment: @Phorce Look at the modified loop. Since the vector is modified, you will miss elements in `blocks`, if you increment regardless of removal or not.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche Thanks for the reply. But, blocks is a 2D array, so, therefore, I cannot use .begin() .end() can I? it gives an error

Comment: @Phorce `blocks` is defined as `vector<iniMatrix> &blocks` in your source code, so I'm curious what error you get. Can you post the precise message?

Answer (score 3):

The third argument to [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) is a predicate function (or any callable entity, for that matter) that takes a single element and returns `true` if it needs to be removed and `false` if not. The element of a vector of vectors (or "2D vector", as you call it) is a vector, `vector<double>` in your case. That's what the argument to your predicate should be:

```
bool HasInsufficientEnergy(const vector<double>& elem)
{
    // herein is the code that tests elem and decides
    // whether it should be removed or not
}
```

Then your `filter()` method shouldn't contain much more than this

```
void Audio::filter(vector<iniMatrix>&blocks)
{
    auto it = std::remove_if(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), &HasInsufficientEnergy);
    blocks.erase(it, blocks.end());
}
```

If your predicate needs aditional arguments, then implement it as a class that takes them as constructor parameters. You need to overload `operator()`, too, so you have a callable functor.
If your compiler supports C++11, then learn how to use lambda functions as they are very useful for exactly this task.

Answer (score 1):

`remove_if`, and similar algorithms, expect a function, not a value, i.e. you should pass a function pointer or functor that an `double const &` and returns a `bool`

```
bool hasInsufficientEnergy(double const & element) {
    // return true if it should be removed, false otherwise
}
```

and then

```
iniMatrix::iterator erase_after = remove_if(blocks[i].begin(), blocks[i].end(), 
&hasInsufficientEnergy);
```

will work

Comment: @Phorce you need an argument, the function has a `double const&` argument, which is the content of the element in the list being looked at

Comment: But why element and not the block? I don't get what double element is supposed to pass??